# Using Async/Await vs Promise.all with for-loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Here is how I understand things currently:

async/await in a for-loop should pause execution until the promise resolves, meaning that the next iteration of the loop won't occur until that line finishes.

Consider the following array:

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
    data.push(i);
}
```

**Method 1: Awaiting Promises in a for-loop**

```
async function method1() {
  const startTime = new Date();
  console.log('start:', startTime);

  for (const item in data) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      if (item % 3 === 0) {
        resolve({});
      } else {
        resolve(item)
      }
    });
  }

  const endTime = new Date();
  console.log('finish:', endTime);
  console.log('total time:', endTime-startTime);
}
```

Because it requires sequential execution of promises to continue through the loop, I figured using Promise.all would be a performance enhancement that leverages asynchronous processing to a greater degree:

**Method 2: Promise.all following a for-loop**

```
async function method2() {
  const promises = [];
  const startTime = new Date();
  console.log('start:', startTime);

  for (const item in data) {
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      if (item % 3 === 0) {
        resolve({});
      } else {
        resolve(item)
      }
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
  const endTime = new Date();
  console.log('finish:', endTime);
  console.log('total time:', endTime-startTime);
}
```

My reasoning: the loop would continue to bang out new Promises while each previously created Promise attempts resolve. So in my head, method 1 = blocking... while method 2 = less blocking.

When I run these both on repl.it, I found that method method 1 is actually quicker, almost by a factor of 2. Can somebody explain why this is? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: The conceptual difference between the two approaches is that one runs the asynchronous operations in parallel, the other runs them in serial. With fake asynchronous operations, you can't see the real effect of that difference.  With real asynchronous operations, the effect would be obvious and running in parallel would have a way faster end-to-end time.  If each asynchronous operation took `200ms` to resolve, then method 1 would resolve in `~n * 200ms` and method 2 would resolve in `~200ms` where n is the number of async operations you run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you resolve too fast, so the looping dominates the execution time, since method2 has two loops: one to push to the array and one for `promise.all` to complete while method1 only has one loop, so your feeling "almost a factor of two" is actually theoretically correct.

Try faking an `actual async operation` like `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))` and you should get what you expected

Comment: Worked like a charm. I guess trying to test asynchronous processes with synchronous operations didn't really make sense huh

Comment: @stoneb Although your code resolves a non-async value, your code is asynchronous as well,  just the 'async' part happened too quickly

Answer (score 2):

To add further to what Drake said. The only reason why method 2 is slower without timeouts is because of the number of loops it will have to encounter, but in a real scenario where request or asynchronous operations have delays. Method 2 will most of the time be faster

Here is the modified snippet with SetTimeout.

```js
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    data.push(i);
}


async function method1() {
  const startTime = new Date();
  console.log('start 1:', startTime);

  for (const item in data) {
   await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        if (item % 3 === 0) {
        resolve({});
      } else {
        resolve(item)
      }
      },1)
    });
  }
  const endTime = new Date();
  console.log('finish 1:', endTime);
  console.log('total time:', endTime-startTime);
}

async function method2() {
  const promises = [];
  const startTime = new Date();
  console.log('start 2:', startTime);

  for (const item in data) {
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        if (item % 3 === 0) {
        resolve({});
      } else {
        resolve(item)
      }
      },1)
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
  const endTime = new Date();
  console.log('finish 2:', endTime);
  console.log('total time:', endTime-startTime);
}

method1()
method2()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code block. That clarified things a lot!